# Multiple inheritence with default implementation not working - forced to always override default implementation

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

**What I want to do**

- I want to have a base interface and a lot of sub interface extenting this base interface
- I want a default implementation of the default interface
- I want that all my sub interface implementations extend the default implementation and only override those methods they want

**I have defined following public interfaces - those are needed this way for the SDK I develop plugins for**

```
// the base interface
class DYNAMIC_ATTRIBUTE IMasterProfile : public IVWUnknown
{
    public:

        virtual Uint16      VCOM_CALLTYPE GetNodeVersion() = 0;
        // ...

}

// one of many sub interfaces extending the default one
class DYNAMIC_ATTRIBUTE ISomeProfile : public IMasterProfile
{
    public:

        virtual void        VCOM_CALLTYPE SwapData() = 0;
};
```

**My implementation looks like following:**

```
class DYNAMIC_ATTRIBUTE MasterProfile : public virtual IMasterProfile
{
    public:
        Uint16 VCOM_CALLTYPE GetNodeVersion() override { return 0; };
        // ...
}

class DYNAMIC_ATTRIBUTE SomeProfile : public MasterProfile, public virtual ISomeProfile
{
    public:
        void VCOM_CALLTYPE SwapData() override { }
}
```

**Problems:**

The compiler complains that `SomeProfile` is abstract and has not implemented  `GetNodeVersion` function. How can I solve this? `SomeProfile` is extenting `MasterProfile` and this class is implementing the `GetNodeVersion` function...

**EDIT: Possible solution**

I can move the `IMasterProfile` default implementation into the header and everything works (additionally I remove the virtual inheritance). I am curious if this can be solved without moving the default implemention into the header...

Comment: Wouldn't this problem go away if your `ISomeProfile` used `public virtual IMasterProfile`?

Comment: I think so too. But the SDK does not allow me to do this. It then complains that it can't convert `IVWUnknown*` into `ISomeProfile*` because of an implicit conversion of a virtual base class...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with ambiguity. You must implement `GetNodeVersion` in `ISomeProfile`. Otherwise `SomeProfile::ISomeProfile::GetNodeVersion` is not defined and it's abstract.
Consider this code:

```
class IMasterProfile
{
public:
    virtual int GetNodeVersion() = 0;
};

class ISomeProfile : public IMasterProfile
{
public:
    virtual void SwapData() = 0;
    int GetNodeVersion() override { return 2; };
};

class MasterProfile : virtual IMasterProfile
{
public:
 int GetNodeVersion() override { return 3; };
// ...
};

class SomeProfile : public MasterProfile, public virtual ISomeProfile
{
public:
    SomeProfile(){ std::cout<<ISomeProfile::GetNodeVersion();}
    void print()
    {
        std::cout<<GetNodeVersion(); // ERROR: Call to the "GetNodeVersion" is ambiguous
        std::cout<<MasterProfile::GetNodeVersion(); // Call to the GetNodeVersion from MasterProfile
        std::cout<<ISomeProfile::GetNodeVersion(); // Call to the GetNodeVersion from ISomeProfile, without implementing it's virtual method
    }
    void SwapData() override { }
};
```

So the problem is line, when you want use in `SomeProfile`:

```
std::cout<<ISomeProfile::GetNodeVersion(); // Call to the GetNodeVersion from ISomeProfile, without implementing it's virtual method
```

Without implementation you can't do it, a definition is needed.